# How to get list of all available public key of transaction manager (used for privateFor field)

Tags: quorum

I have deployed a quorum cluster with docker-compose.
I want to deploy a private contract between node 1 and node 2.
But how can I get public key of transaction manager of node 2?
Or how can I find the list of all public key?

Answer (score 0):

The public key is specified in the config file for the transaction manager. It should be the value of the `publicKey` field of the config file.

There's no programatic way of getting the public key value, so you need to shell into your docker container and look at the TM config file (or you can look at the original value that was provided to the docker-compose.yml).